# How may I quit iPhoto without saving modifications?

Tags: photos.app, macos

I am working with a huge photo library and from time to time I experiment quick editing on some pictures. Sometimes I also make uncontrolled changes which apply on a set of pictures I can't correctly see.

In these situations I would like to be able to exit `iPhoto` without saving these unwanted modifications.

I didn't find any preference permetting to achieve **this wanted behaviour**. Hopefully I have this basic function on most applications which can modify files or libraries beyond what the user can see.

Is there any hidden `defaults` of `iPhoto` which would give access to such a simple function?

I am actually running `iPhoto '11`, but I'm interested by this function for any version running on Lion, Mountain Lion & Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

From the menu at the top select "Photos > Revert to Original".

This also works if you select multiple photos/events.

Answer (score 0):

iPhoto saves as you go [same as iMovie, Final Cut Pro etc] - but it always preserves the original file & you can revert at any time...

From Photos menu > Revert to Original.

I don't know of any way to 'reset' in bulk if you have been working on multiple images.